# importing error after changing folder name

Tags: python, pandas

I was working on a python project everything was going great all imported libraries have no issues.

but after changing the project folder name it keep saying that pandas `"Import "pandas" could not be resolved from sourcePylance"`

How can I solve this problem ?

ide: vscode / python version: 3.10.2 / OS: Windows11

Comment: Could you provide IDE, python version, OS?

Comment: @Sala ide vscode / python version 3.10.2 / OS : Windows11

Comment: Try this https://youtu.be/Z0lkdAmul_A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What was happening is that I have multiple python versions so changing the interpreter in vsCode solved the problem